# Дублирование кода

Tags: c++, ооп, xcode, классы

Вылетает ошибка "2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64" в Xcode. Скорее всего из-за неправильного подключения файлов. В чем проблема не совсем понятно.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"
#include "A.cpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "B.cpp"

int main() {

    A a;
    B b;

    a.funC(b);
    b.funC(a);

    return 0;
}
```

A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_hpp
#define A_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "B.hpp"

class B;

class A {
    int numA = 0;
public:
    int getNum () {return numA;}

    void funC (B &b);
};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

void A::funC (B &b) {
    std::cout << b.getNum() << std::endl;
}
```

B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_hpp
#define B_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"

class A;

class B {

    int numB = 1;

public:
    int getNum () {return numB;}

    void funC (A &a);
};

#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"

void B::funC (A &a) {
    std::cout << a.getNum()  << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну и зачем же вы вот это делаете?!

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "A.cpp"   // !!!!!!!!!!
#include "B.hpp"
#include "B.cpp"   // !!!!!!!!!!
```

В результате функции у вас есть как в `main.cpp`, так и в ваших `a.cpp` и `b.cpp`!

Или компилируете вот такой `main.cpp`, **не** подключая в проект `a.cpp` и `b.cpp`, или делаете нормальный проект из 3 файлов, не включая `*.cpp` как заголовочный!

Answer (score 2):

в #include не нужно подключать файлы *.cpp, исключительно заголовки, то есть *.hpp